# Display sql result in listview based on dropdown list choice

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a dropdown menu with a list of buyers and I am trying to bind an sql query result to the listview based on user choice in the dropdown. Below is the code but the listview doesn't show at all.

```
 protected void DropDownListSearchByBuyer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Web_FussConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Team_Name FROM Team WHERE Team_ID = @Team_ID", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Team_ID", DropDownListSearchByBuyer.Text);
        con.Open();



        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        ListView1.DataSource = reader;
        ListView1.DataBind();

    }
```

Listview code

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception? and where is your list view design code?

Comment: I'm not getting any exception, it loads fine. See edit above for listview code

Comment: Place a breakpoint and step through to see if you're getting any value back from the database

Comment: Is `Autopostback` is set to `true` in your dropdown markup.

Answer (score 0):

> Add ItemTemplate in Listview for display column like below.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <span><%# Eval("Team_Name") %><span>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

See article for more details : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx

Comment: That unfortunately didn't fix it. Still doesn't load the list view at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
    void SetListView()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Web_FussConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Team_Name FROM Team WHERE Team_ID = @Team_ID", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Team_ID", DropDownListSearchByBuyer.Text);
        con.Open();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        var readerdata = GetReaderData(reader);
        reader.Close();
        reader = null;
        con.Close();
        con = null;

        ListView1.DataSource = readerdata;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }

    DataTable GetReaderData(IDataReader reader)
    {
        DataTable dtSchema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        DataTable readerData = new DataTable();

        if (dtSchema == null)
        {
            return readerData;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dtSchema.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = dtSchema.Rows[i]["ColumnName"].ToString();
            readerData.Columns.Add(dc);
        }


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            DataRow dr = readerData.NewRow();

            for (int i = 0; i < readerData.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                dr[readerData.Columns[i].ColumnName] = reader[readerData.Columns[i].ColumnName];
            }
            readerData.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        return readerData;
    }
```

> Always `Close` reader after reading data